# Jquery ajax get, load X amount data from xml file?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml, get

I have a XML file like this:

[image]

What is the best wayway to load the 2 first message-tags?

Comment: Did you tried any thing or searched for the problem?

Comment: The first step is to spell your tags correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.ajax` to retrieve the XML, and then select the first two messages:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/file.xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        var $messages = $(xml).find('chat messages').slice(0,2);

        // do something with the messages here...
    }
});
```

Comment: I knew i had seen it somewhere, but couldn't find it. Thank you!